# GeoServer does not render polygon properly

Tags: geoserver, polygon-creation, rendering, polygonize, rasterization

I am trying to a get polygon layer from CSV file. I chose to do it via rasterization and polygonization in QGIS, however, GeoServer has problems correctly rendering some polygons.

This is how the layer looks in QGIS (how it should look like):

[image]

And here is how the layer looks displayed from GeoServer (using OpenLayers):

[image]

You can see that at some point it is weirdly distorted, maybe kind of inverted. I read the Q/A *GeoServer renders shape incorrectly* both on [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655289/geoserver-renders-shape-incorrectly) and here at [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80863/geoserver-renders-shape-incorrectly-distorted). However, I am still lost. SRS of the layers should be set correctly as I have a lot of similar layers and its happens just for about 10% of them. If it is an issue of

> caused by how different products create polygons. (...) From the GeoServer documentation it requires that polygons have the same first and last coordinate. I would recommend that you edit the polygons in the shapefile to accomplish this.

as suggested by Darkcylde. How can I fix it? What is more important, how can I avoid it, since I am in total control of layers production and it happens for about 10 % of them?

I found out that when I rasteryze the CSV file with too high resolution causing the layers "granulation" the problem vanishes (but the picture is useless):

[image]

Here are the [files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a7irs3vs4t44dum/AABqai6B8g3H2iZt3zIJ61WYa?dl=0) which I use to create the layer. I used the modelNo of value 4.

And here is the Python code used in QGIS:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from time import sleep
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, QColor, QPainter

# change the import
import processing

class Loader:
    def __init__(self,iface):
       """Initialize using the qgis.utils.iface 
       object passed from the console.
       """
       self.iface = iface

    def create_models(self):
        print "inside a function"
        m = 11
        h = 16
        f = 4
        ss = "%02dm%02dh%dflx" % (m,h,f)

        uri = "file:///d:/GISdata/THRASH/ModGrids/MODgrid%s.dat?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=epsg:4326" % (ss,",", "long", "lat")
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "MODgrid", "delimitedtext")

        writename = "d:/GISdata/THRASH/Temp/ModGridm%s.shp" % (ss)
        write = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,writename,"WGS84", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
        sleep(3)
        shLayer = QgsVectorLayer(writename,"PoinData", "ogr")

        raststore1 = "d:/GISdata/THRASH/Temp/testResh1.tif"
        processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",shLayer,"modelNo",0,360,340,raststore1)

        NTCMname1 = "d:/GISdata/THRASH/Temp/1NTCM%s.shp" % (ss)
        processing.runalg("gdalogr:polygonize",raststore1,"DN",NTCMname1)
        player1 = QgsVectorLayer(NTCMname1, "NTCM", "ogr")
        ids = [f.id() for f in player1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"DN"!=4'))]
        player1.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids)
```

Comment: You data crosses the -/+180 degree line so it it wrapping itself across the projection, make your data 179.5 degrees east/west it should solve the issue.

Comment: @Mapperz good point, unfortunately that did not solve the problem: (